# Modifying response headers in Chrome extensions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

I'm trying to modify the referer-policy header with my Chrome extension, but it doesn't affect the response headers.

`Manifest.json:`

```json
{
  "name": "My Example Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "",
  "permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "*://*/*"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

`background.js:`

```js
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(details => {
    let header = details.responseHeaders.find(e => e.name.toLowerCase() === 'referrer-policy');

    // Check if the header has been defined already
    if (typeof header !== 'undefined') {
        console.log ('Modifying header');
        header.value = 'strict-origin';
    }
    else {
        details.responseHeaders.push({ name: 'referrer-policy', value: 'strict-origin' });
    }

    return {responseHeaders: details.responseHeaders};
}, {urls: ["*://*/*"]}, ['blocking', 'responseHeaders']);
```

I added debug outputs which show that the code modifies or adds the header accordingly but there is no effect in the browser itself.

Comment: As the documentation says, only one extension may modify responseHeaders for each request.

Comment: I disabled all other extensions and the problem persists.

Comment: You are modifying your local copy of the header (`let header = ... ; header.value = ... `) but not the response you return.

Comment: Assuming you're not running a very old version of Chrome, it sounds like a bug in the browser, which you can report on https://crbug.com (make sure to attach a demo extension).

Comment: @wOxxOm I am running Chrome 70.0.3538.77.

Comment: @Iván Nokonoko In that case the push should still work which it doesn't.

Comment: The push only works if the Referrer-Policy header is not present in the request. If it is present, you modify your local copy of it but don't update the value you return.

Answer (score 9):

I was writing exactly the same code when trying to modify response headers in extension.

```js
// manifest.json

  "permissions": [
    "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "https://developer.chrome.com/*"
  ]

// background.js

chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(
  function(details) {
    const newHeader = {name:"foo", value:"bar"};
    const responseHeaders = details.responseHeaders.concat(newHeader);
    return { responseHeaders };
  },
  // filters
  {
    urls: ["https://developer.chrome.com/*"],
  },
  // extraInfoSpec
  ["blocking","responseHeaders"]
);
```

It just doesn't work at all.

Until I've changed the last argument to:

```js
  // extraInfoSpec
  ["blocking","responseHeaders", "extraHeaders"]
```

It finally works.

By revisiting the document, in the last paragraphs of [Life cycle of requests](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#life_cycle) section:

> Starting from Chrome 79, ... On the other hand, response header modifications do not work to deceive CORS checks. If you need to deceive the CORS protocol, you also need to specify '`extraHeaders`' for the response modifications.

Answer (score 0):

You were not returning the modified headers. Try with:

```js
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(details => {
    let myResponseHeaders = details.responseHeaders;
    let header = myResponseHeaders.find(e => e.name == 'Referrer-Policy');

    // Check if the header has been defined already
    if (header) {
        console.log ('Modifying header');
        let headerIndex = myResponseHeaders.indexOf(header);
        myResponseHeaders.splice(headerIndex,1);
    }
    
    myResponseHeaders.push({ name: 'Referrer-Policy', value: 'strict-origin' });
    

    return {responseHeaders: myResponseHeaders};
}, {urls: ["*://*/*"]}, ['blocking', 'responseHeaders']);
```

Or with a slightly modified code copied from the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#examples):

```js
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(
    function(details) {
      for (var i = 0; i < details.responseHeaders.length; ++i) {
        if (details.responseHeaders[i].name === 'Referrer-Policy') {
          details.responseHeaders[i].value = 'strict-origin';
          break;
        }
      }
      return {responseHeaders: details.responseHeaders};
    },
    {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
    ["blocking", "responseHeaders"]
);
```

Comment: I get this error in the line with findIndex: "Error in event handler for webRequest.onHeadersReceived/1: TypeError: #<Object> is not a function"

Comment: I used indexOf instead and now it doesn't throw an error but still doesn't change the header.